# mouseMoveEvent not working in QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, drawing, pyqt

I am trying to implement a paint program in PyQt4. In the QGraphicsScene, I use the mouseMoveEvent to draw lines connecting the consecutive mouse co-ordinates.
The code is as follows:

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):                        
    x1 = event.pos().x()
    y1 = event.pos().y()       
    self.addLine(self.x0, self.y0, x1, y1, self.pen)    
    self.x0, self.y0 = x1, y1
```

x0, y0 are initialized as 0,0.

The problem I encounter is that, when I click the mousebutton *a single point* is drawn at (0,0), and no more drawing takes place.
The same mouseMoveEvent works perfectly in QGraphicsView. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: can  you post a working example?

Comment: @gruszczy: stop this. if you need many question re-tagged post a request on meta. don't pollute active questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The above code is fine, except that `event.pos()` does not work in QGraphicsScene. Inorder to capture the mouseEvent's co-ordinates in QGraphicsScene, we must use `event.scenePos()`